# monocular Camera calibration in ROS

Tags: calibration, ros-fuerte, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was trying the camera calibration from the following link: link:[text](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration) and my camera feed is shown in one window of the GUI (There is another window derectly below this but it is blank). The problem is that my checkerboard will not highlight.

I printed out a 7x7 checkerboard where each square is 0.024 meters. I tried the camera from my webcam but it could not detect like it does in the tutorial. I get the window but "calibrate" "save" and "commit" are hazed out and there are no "x" "y" and "size" highlighted like in the tutorial.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80766/monocular-camera-calibration-in-ros/) by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2013-09-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/41511/camera_calibration-checkerboard-target-not-found/). My guess is you are just as confused as I was back then: the size variable refers to the number of inner corners, not the number of squares.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2013-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-09-18**:
Thanks so much! Doing 6x6 worked perfectly.

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-09-18**:
Isn't the documentation confusing? I'm glad I could help, I remember it took me forever to figure this out (almost a month!)

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-09-18**:
Yea it sure is! It took me a week to figure out that I even had to use a checkerboard to calibrate the camera! The page I linked should state it much clearer but hopefully this post will help many others in the future! I really appreciate your help, thanks once again!